# python file in-out adding last three characters

Tags: python, macos, gedit

Ok, so basic python question. I have a simple script to replace text on html(txt) files. I wrote some code and put in some newline html that had xhtml coding i wanted to replace so I tried to write a python script to replace the xhtml coding versions with regular newline html.
Sometimes when I run the code, it works fine, but sometimes it rewrites the file, and at the end the last two characters are repeated after a newline. I'm running 2.7 on OS X Lion, if that matters. Here's the code:

```
import sys
import re

def replace_text(filename): 
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        p = re.compile( '(</br>|<br/>|<br />)')
    f_data = open(filename, 'r+').read()
    f.write(p.sub('<br>', f_data))
    f.close()

def main():
args = sys.argv[1:]

if not args:
    print 'usage: [--summaryfile] file [file ...]'
    sys.exit(1)

summary = False

if args[0] == '--summaryfile':
    summary = Trye
    del args[0]

for filename in args:
    replace_text(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

So when I run it with a file (say 'foo.txt') that has the content:

```
</br> <br/> <br /> <br> poop
```

sometimes it outputs:

```
<br> <br> <br> <br> poop
```

and sometimes it outputs:

```
<br> <br> <br> <br> poop
op
```

huh? Using OS X Lion with python 2.7. I'm missing something simple? Also using Gedit 3.2.6 as an editor. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shortening the content of the file, but you're not shortening its length. Don't forget to do so via `.truncate()` before closing.

Comment: Huge success. Thank you so much! Also, please forgive my indentation errors here, the code is indented right, but I'm virtualizing OS X Lion through Win7, and it's not running perfect, so I have trouble getting keyboard commands through and screwed up copying my code into the form. I'm also new (obviously from my reputation) to stackoverflow. But you're awesome for catching my dumb error. Thanks.